# Debugging Typescript with IntelliJ and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, typescript, intellij-idea

Is there a way to find the corresponding line in a Typescript file to the (compiled) Javascript one that is causing an error?

I am using IntelliJ and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with the source map support. Is will create a `.js.map` file that matches the JavaScript files with the TypeScript source. Chrome (and all other browsers as well) will be able to use that to show `.ts` files while debugging.

For the command line compiler you can add the `--sourceMap` option ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) to enable this.

---

To configure the built-in compiler, follow the instructions from [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/compiling-typescript-to-javascript.html) documentation:

> Choose the **Set options manually** to configure compilation manually:
>
> Select the **Generate source maps** check box to generate source maps that set correspondence between lines in your TypeScript code and in the generated JavaScript code, otherwise your breakpoints will not be recognised and processed correctly.

Comment: Seems that enabling **source maps** solves issues with non working TS debugger. Thank you : )